# Retracted Close Votes shouldn't be listed under 'Profile > Votes' indistinguishable from retained ones

Tags: feature-request, bug, profile-page, vote-to-close, retracted-close-votes

The title pretty much says it all. When one votes to close a question, retracts their close-vote, and then goes to the [`Votes` tab on their profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes), the question is still listed there as "Closure" even though the vote was retracted.

That seems like a bug to me, but regardless, we currently have no way of knowing if a vote listed there has been retracted without clicking on the question *and then* opening the close dialog and checking the status.

Can you please do one of the following?

- Hide/remove the retracted close votes from that list. Or...
- if there's in fact a good reason to keep them, then add a way to indicate that the vote has been retracted.

Comment: The vote was still cast, so the history should remain. Isn't the retraction visible as well? [tag:status-bydesign] I think.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Testing this bug

Comment: This works the same way across the network, at least here ;)

Comment: @Mast Yes, the history should remain but listing it under close votes is confusing, IMO. I mean retracted flags are listed under a separate category. However, with close votes, if you go to the `Votes` tab, you have no way of knowing that you had retracted your vote without opening the question and then the close dialog. If this turned out to be `status-bydesign`, perhaps I should post it as a `feature-request` to display some indication that the vote was retracted?