# Can we know who voted to close a question and then retracted their vote?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close, retracted-close-votes

Some time ago, I was browsing through the history of the close votes review queue of a group and I noticed that a certain question had been closed after five users having voted there to close it (and no user voted to keep it open). I found that strange: how had that question got there in the first place? As far as I know, a question is sent to the close votes review queue only if some user votes to close it (am I right?).

Then I thought that what could have happened was this: a user voted to close the question and then retracted their vote. This would explain it. Is that the only explanation? Is it possible to know who that user was (my guess is that it is not)? Or, at last, do the group moderators have access to that information?

Comment: Another possibility was that the question was flagged for closure by a <3k user, which puts the question into review. Anyway, as far as I'm aware, moderators can view close vote information, including retracted votes.

Comment: Yes, that is another possibility. I missed it.

Comment: Not really:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/915/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353942/282094  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252586/3648282 --- If someone flags they are *hidden* that info is private, if their vote (flag) ages it drops out while newer ones come into effect (hiding the original closer), even if they retract their own (private) history still shows them as a closer so even they don't know, and the list can be huge on some sites. --- Even if implementation has changed from those links above the software wasn't designed to disclose this info to regular users. Tag FR.

Comment: Why would you really need to know? I'm not sure in what way is this information relevant. Even ***if*** a user VTC'd and retracted their vote, this could be for a variety of reasons.Or maybe the question was flagged, as @SonictheK-DayHedgehog says. Or maybe it was something else. I'm not sure why that information is relevant.

Comment: @VLAZ It's relevant for detecting whether or not a certain user is systematically voting to close questions from (or answered by) another specific user. That user could cast a closing vote and some time later, before the question got closed, retract the vote. I wanted to know whether that procedure can go undetected.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos surely, if user A is VTCing user B's questions *and they are closed* then user B's questions should have been closed in the first place. Assuming you mean multiple instances here. I am not sure I'm ready to believe that user A has a grand conspiracy plan to VTC and retract in the hopes that the close queue mistakenly votes to close many question of user B when they are absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community consensus in the form of close votes was that the question you were looking at needed to be improved in order to be eligible for answers.

I think it is important to focus on the content of that question and its improvement rather than trying to identify any individual who may have changed their mind about whether it needs improvement, *if* that is what happened.